# Having trouble with running react.js on WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, webstorm, antivirus, react-fullstack

After I have installed Bootstrap for React I can't run a project. It shows me antivirus error:

[image: error]

I have tried `npm uninstall`, deleting that project and making another but still same error. Scanning whole PC with avast shows no problem:

[image: no problem]

Searching on Google about it have found no useful info. Also when I make for example in WebStorm node.js project or node-express it works and runs just fine, but React is just being blocked.

Does anyone know what it can be and how to fix that? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the web storm, it's maybe the antivirus setup you are using that is returning false positive alarm. That is why your PowerShell is blocked and you are not able to run your project. Try installing gitbash, avast antivirus set up won't block it and you will be able to run your project.